# How to specify firebase database rules "out of the scope"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database structure looks like this now:

```
database: {
  users: {
    uniqueUserId1: {
      name: "an user",
      company: "Company1",
      rank: "manager"
    }
  }
  rota: {
    Company1: {
      2018: "rota for 2018"
    }
  }
}
```

So I don't want to let users read all companies rotas, just they own company's rota.

For user rules it's not too hard:

```
rules: {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },

    //But a bit complicated for things "outside the scope".
    //What I want is something like:

    "rota": {
      "$company": {
        ".read": "$company === users[auth.uid].company",
        ".write": "$company === users[auth.uid].company && users[auth.uid].rank === 'manager'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that these rules aren't working, but how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build the path to the user data by starting with `root`. So you're looking for something like this:

```
".read": "$company === root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('company').val()",
```

Also see:

- [the revised chat example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example)

Comment: child(auth.uid) should be without single quotes

Comment: Good catch! Fixed.